# Problem when running flutter app on android device or emulator

Tags: android, flutter, adb

adb: failed to install C:\Users\Jeet\App Projects\learning_firebase\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.example.learning_firebase signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!]
Error launching application on RMX2151.

I used usb debugging to connect my phone to laptop
Then used Run without debugging

Comment: uninstall the app and build-run again

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall the app from the device `RMX2151` and run the app again. Make sure the `Developer Options` are enabled and `USB Debugging` is checked.